# Не обновляются данные по порту при создании вебсервера на localhost Intellij IDEA

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, maven, tomcat, порт

Решил создать тестовый сайт на Spring Java, сгенерировал шаблон на start.spring.io. Запустил, всё в порядке, но в дальнейшем когда изменял код зареранил проект, а мой стандартный порт 8080 занят, команды server.servlet 8080(или любой другой свободный) и тд, а также копания в настройках не помогли, ощущение, что когда я завершаю процесс работы кода, порт всё также висит за этим процессом и не обновляется. Возможно ошибка в операционке?

Через командную строку искал процесс, занимающий 8080, как раз, тот процесс, который является предыдущим, имел тот же PID

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, вместо порта 8080 - поставить например 9090. Скорей всего порт 8080 кто-то еще прослушивает(программа). У меня такое было когда запускал IDEA в два окна (два проекта и запускал), они начинали бороться за порт - 8080.

Comment: Дело не в этом, я уже пробовал ставить другие свободные порты. Дело в том, что процесс корректно не завершает работу с портом, но как это технически исправить я не знаю.